# Exit App Confirmation Dialog Appearing Multiple Times

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an application with two pages mainly main and second.

I am traversing from main to second and vice-a-verse.

`MainActivity.java` has following code:

```
Button btnSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSecond);

    btnSecond .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
```

`Second.java` has following code:

```
Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        btnClose .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent j = new Intent(Second.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(j);
            }
        });
```

I have added the app exit confirmation dialog function in `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }
```

The problem is that when i come from second page to main page and then press the back button on the device i get the alert two times.

As far as my understanding is concerned this happens because the MainActivity was loaded twice in the background : one when i clicked on the second button on the main page and traversed to the second screen and second when i clicked on the close button on the second page and traversed to the main page.

What i want is that the there should be a single confirmation dialog and clicking on yes should close the main activity even if it is loaded multiple times.

Comment: On `btnClose` just call `MainActivity.this.finish();` method instead of `Intent j = new Intent(Second.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(j);`

Comment: Why you starting another activity on btnClose ?

Comment: Thanks piyush for reply i cannot call finish() because if the user goes to the second page and presses the back button he should be directed to main page.

Comment: Thanks juned for reply, it is just a dummy in actual application i am sending some data to the main page.

Comment: When you call finish() on button close it will redirect to you on your main page.

Comment: Why are you putting a confirmation dialog?  Android does not need them, users hate them and it is against the Google design guidelines.  Do you expect yo exit a web page?

Answer (score 1):

You should not call first activity again you can just call finish on second activity. I think this will sort out your problem.

```
Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        btnClose .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Second.this.finish();
            }
        });
```

on mainactivity.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you call your second activity use:

```
btnSecond .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
        j.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(j);
    }
});
```

and you have to call `super.onBackPressed();`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks sagar for replying. I am getting following error: The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: try `MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();`

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` when you start your second Activity

```
Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
startActivity(j);
finish();
```

this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks juned for reply i cannot call finish() because if the user goes to the second page and presses the back button he should be directed to main page.

Answer (score 0):

please change code in second activity button click listener

`Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

```
    btnClose .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });`
```

Your problem is solve.

`finish()` function kill your activity.

Please check it.